# Mule 4 Object Store always returns null on retrieve

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I'm using the following version of the runtime and object store respectively.

```
<app.runtime>4.2.2-hf2</app.runtime>
<mule.maven.plugin.version>3.3.5</mule.maven.plugin.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-objectstore-connector</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5</version>
    <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Object Store config

```
<os:object-store name="tokenStore" maxEntries="1" entryTtl="1" entryTtlUnit="HOURS" expirationInterval="60" config-ref="ObjectStore_Config" persistent="false"/>
```

I have an HTTP request in my flow that retrieves an authentication key that I want other flows to share. I save the response in a variable to then store its value.

```
<logger level="INFO" message="Authentication Response: #[vars.authResponse]" />
<os:store key="accessToken" objectStore="tokenStore">
    <os:value><![CDATA[#[vars.authResponse.access_token]]]></os:value>
</os:store>
<os:retrieve key="accessToken" objectStore="tokenStore" target="vars.accessToken" >
</os:retrieve>
<logger level="INFO" message="Retrieve from store: #[vars.accessToken]"/>
```

Here's the log output:

```
WMS Authentication Response: {"access_token":"123","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}
Retrieve from store: null
```

I can't figure out why the stored value si always null when I try to retrieve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Based on personal experience - I would change Object store for good database. https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/IgnoreUnreliableObjectStorage.html

Comment: Does Mule provide any other tool I can use for the purpose of storing expiring values? The authentication token I'm working with has a use of an hour before expiring so I want my application to use that token until it has to request a new one and I thought Object Store would fulfill that need. I'm basically trying to avoid calling the authentication endpoint for every single call when I can re-use a single token. @Alex

Answer (score 0):

Try logging the value of vars.authResponse.access_token before storing it. vars.authResponse appears to be JSON, and maybe it is not being interpreted correctly by the expression. You might need to set the type manually.

Example:

```
<os:value><![CDATA[#[output application/java --- vars.authResponse.access_token]]]></os:value>
```

Comment: So logging the `access_token` property specifically will still give me the string value of the token. I added the `output application/java` to the store value but I'm still getting null when retrieving.